# missing separator line between Actionitems in ActionSheet ios

Tags: ios, ipad, uiactionsheet

i am creating an Action Sheet but a separator line is missing between the last two item. Check the last items VIC and WA. Any ideas?

```
- (IBAction)stateButtonClick:(id)sender
{
    statesSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"Select State"
                                             delegate:self
                                             cancelButtonTitle:Nil
                                             destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                             otherButtonTitles: @"ACT",@"NSW",@"NT",@"QLD",@"SA",@"TAS",@"VIC",@"WA", nil];
    [statesSheet showFromRect:_stateTextField.frame inView:self.view animated:true];
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Nitin..The link gave me the result.

Comment: yes its work on iOS 6